# Qt: mouseMoveEvent and interfer with hoverEnterEvent of child object

Tags: c++, qt, hover, qgraphicsview, mousemove

I use `QGraphicsView` to create a sort of circut editor, which has elements in it, which have connectors. It should be possible to connect those connectors with wires.
However, I have a problem, while I drag from one connector to another, Qt grabs mouse, and other connectors stop receiving `hoverEnterEvent`. Btw, on hover connectors resize, so it's easier to hit them.

Once again, is it possible not to grab mouse while drag?

I have used Qt 4.5 for Windows.

As requested, here are some sources:
http://pastebin.com/m422b9495

Comment: Can you post sources / stripped down version to prevent others from having to (possibly erroneously) recreate your environment? You might have to call QApplication::processEvents() or turn on mouse tracking for this to work.

Comment: Have your QGraphicsItems the QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable flag with true?

Comment: No, QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable is false.

Comment: Could you add the sources into the question. Especially since it appears the link to pastebin has expired.

Comment: Sorry, I can't! This question is 3 years old...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set [interactive mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#interactive-prop) to false.

See also [DragMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#DragMode-enum)

> ScrollHandDrag
>
> > The cursor changes into a pointing hand, and dragging the mouse around will scroll the scrolbars. This mode works both in interactive and non-interactive mode.
>
> RubberBandDrag
>
> > A rubber band will appear. Dragging the mouse will set the rubber band geometry, and all items covered by the rubber band are selected. This mode is disabled for non-interactive views.

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat typical to change the mouse-over behavior during a drag operation. Widgets that normally respond to mouse movement tend to not respond during a drag unless they can receive the associated drop. So the usual hover events are suppressed. (Checking whether or not a widget accepts some drops is inadequate since the question is whether or not the widget might accept this drop.) Try using the drag's enter and leave events to resize your connectors, in addition to the hover events.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mouseMoveEvent in the source item to check when the cursor is over the target item.

For example:

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    item = self.scene().itemAt(event.scenePos(), self.scene().views([0].transform())

    if isinstance(item, NodeConnectionGraphicItem):
        if self.item_over_drag is None:
            self.item_over_drag = item
            item.highlighted_mouse_over = True
            ...
            item.update()
    elif self.item_over_drag is not None:
        self.item_over_drag.highlighted_mouse_over = False
        self.item_over_drag.update()
        self.item_over_drag = None
```